# MS Access vba, open select query with parameters, run-time 3065 cannot execute a select query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting frustrated trying to open a select query with a "parameter" set.  I fully suspect I am building my query all wrong. I want a form with an unbound date textbox for the user to input a date (I have this). Then I want that date passed to a prestored parameter select query and the query opens.  If I open the query manually it asks for the [Compare Date] as expected.  When I use the form, click a button to open the query the qdf.execute fails.

Fictitious query for demo

```
PARAMETERS [Compare Date] DateTime;
SELECT [Compare Date] AS Compare_date;
```

I know that "parameters" are usually in the WHERE clause but, again, this query works if run manually.

Then below is the calling code

```
Private Sub btnRunReport_Click()

    Const pstr_CURRENCY_QRY As String = "Query12"
    Const pstr_DATA_PARAM As String = "Compare Date"
    Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(pstr_CURRENCY_QRY)
    With qdf
        .Parameters(pstr_DATA_PARAM).Value = CDate(Me.txtCompareDate.Value)
        .Execute dbFailOnError  ' <<<< Fails here
        .Close
    End With    ' qdf
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this or come at it with a different approach so that the query works manually and via the form?

Comment: Fails - How? Error? Just crashes?

Comment: Just gives me the runtime error in the subject on the .execute line. No further information is given. I used the immediate window to confirm the parameter is being set and it is. It just will not open the select query

Comment: If it is a RunTime Error, you will be given an Error Number and Error Description.

Comment: I did, per the subject 3065 cannot execute select query @HansUp seems to be onto the problem in that it is not a parameter issue as it is the .Execute method cannot open a select query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `DAO Execute` method for a `SELECT` query.  That is why Access complains *"Cannot execute a select query."*

The parameter issue is not relevant here.

Decide what you want to do with the result set your parameter query returns.  If you want to load it into a recordset, you can use the `QueryDef`'s `OpenRecordset` method.

Comment: Ultimately I'd like to output it to an excel spreadsheet for distro.

Comment: I figured out a work around. Probably not too elegant but I take the qdf.sql, use a find and replace, CreateQueryDef for a temp query, then I use the DoCmd.OpenQuery.